# Unique exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

While reading that article [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula) I was confused by the **note** saing that there is another formula for exterior derivative differing by a constant. On the other hand from what I have checked in my differential geometry book that operator is UNIQUE so how is it possible?

Comment: How is it defined in your book? It could be that the axioms are slightly different in the wiki definition. In any case, this is probably an example of the operator being "unique up to a scalar." For example, if you define the determinant axiomatically, it might be uniquely determined *up to a scalar multiple*, which is often taken to be defined as normalizing the determinant of the identity. You should check your book to see if the exterior derivative as defined there truly is *unique* or if it is only unique up to multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: OTOH, it might simply be that your book and the wiki uses one definition, and the version used by Kobayashi–Nomizu and Helgason is simply defined in such a way that it is a scalar multiple of your definition. In this case, the seeming lack of uniqueness is just due to differing conventions.

Comment: hmmm I think the problem is bigger because both definitions require $d(\alpha \wedge \beta)= d \alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^p \alpha \wedge d \beta$ and operator made from operator fullfiling that by multiplication by degree of a form does not fulfill that property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exterior derivative is the unique operator satisfying the [three axioms given in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_axioms): $df$ is the differental when $f$ is a function, $d(df)=0$, and $d(\alpha\wedge\beta) = d\alpha\wedge\beta + (-1)^p\alpha\wedge d\beta$ when $\alpha$ is a $p$-form. The reason Kobayashi and Nomizu and Helgason have to use a different formula for $d\omega$ is because they use a different definition of the wedge product.

Comment: I rethought that and have couple things I would like to ask:
1) exterior derivative is the same operator in both cases and it is defined for differential forms as sections of exterior power of cotangent boundle
2) for differential forms as sections wedge product is the same in both cases because wedge product is defined as unique bilinear map with some properties ?
3) the difference is with the identification section <-> multilinear antysymetric map (equivalently with the wedge product for forms seen as multilinear maps) ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is yes: The only real choice is in how to identify elements of the exterior powers of the cotangent bundle with multilinear functions on the tangent bundle. The two different choices give rise to two different wedge products.